# Use absolute value for label text in ggplot proportion bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show absolute values for the data points in a proportion bar chart using ggplot2.

Here is the code:

```
mtcars_gear_by_make <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  tidyr::separate(car, c("make", "model"), sep = "\\s", extra = "merge") %>%
  dplyr::filter(make == "Merc" | make == "Toyota") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(make, gear) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(n_model = n())
```

And this is the tibble the code creates:

```
# Groups:   make [2]
  make    gear n_model
  <chr>  <dbl>   <int>
1 Merc       3       3
2 Merc       4       4
3 Toyota     3       1
4 Toyota     4       1
```

I used this code to generate the proportion bar chart:

```
ggplot(mtcars_gear_by_make,
       aes(x = make, y = n_model, fill = gear)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Is there a way to add labels to the bar chart to show `Merc` has 3 models with gear 3 and 4 models with gear 4, and `Toyota` has 1 model with gear 3 and 1 model with gear 4?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you have to create the position `p` because you show in proportion style on y-axis and then use that in `geom_text()` (I modified the code to compute that):

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars_gear_by_make <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  tidyr::separate(car, c("make", "model"), sep = "\\s", extra = "merge") %>%
  dplyr::filter(make == "Merc" | make == "Toyota") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(make, gear) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(n_model = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(p=n_model/sum(n_model))

ggplot(mtcars_gear_by_make,
       aes(x = make, y = n_model, fill = gear,label=n_model)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")+
  geom_text(aes(y=p),position = position_stack(vjust = .5),color='white',fontface='bold')
```

[image]